# Expected Value of a Transformed Variable

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose there is a random variable $Y$ and $X$ such that:

For $0 \leq X \leq 3$, $Y=0.2$.

For $X \geq 3$, $Y = 0.2 + 0.08(X-3)$.

If $X$ follows an exponential distribution ($E[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda})$.

What is the $E[Y]$?

---

I tried to solve this problem by calculating $\int^{3}_{0}0.2xdx + \int^{\infty}_3 x[0.02+0.08(\lambda e^{-\lambda x}-3)]dx$. But this results in an answer of infinity ($\int^{\infty}_3 0.02xdx$), so I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use $$\mathsf E Y=\mathsf E_X (\mathsf E Y|X)$$
So $$\mathsf E Y|X=\begin{cases} 0.2, & 0\le x\le3\\
0.2+0.08(x-3) & x\ge 3\\
\end{cases}$$
Now calculate the expectation with respect to $X$:
$$\mathsf EY=\mathsf E_X(\mathsf EY|X)=\int_0^30.2f_X(x)dx+\int_3^{\infty}(0.2+0.08(x-3))f_X(x)dx$$
which further boils down to
$$\mathsf EY=(0.2)F_X(3)+(0.2-0.24)(1-F_X(3))+(0.08)\int_3^{\infty} xf_X(x)dx$$
Where $F_X(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ is the exponential cdf. Simplification leads to
$$\mathsf EY=0.2-(0.24)e^{-3\lambda}+(0.08)\frac{(3\lambda+1)e^{-3\lambda}}{\lambda}$$

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I wanted to ask, where did you get the term $\frac{0.08}{\lambda}$? I thought that $\int^{\infty}_{0}xf_X(x) = EX$, and here we have $\int^{\infty}_{3}xf_X(x)$.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation doesn't make sense to me.

Note that $Y$ is a function of $X$. Thus one can write $Y=g(X)$.

Can you find what $g$ is?

Now 
$$
E(Y)=E(g(X))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)dx
$$
where $f_X(x)$ is the density of $X$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification